# Prevent developers in pushing the code with lint errors

Tags: node.js, git, web-deployment

What is the best method to prevent others from pushing the code with lint errors in a project environment with git/nodejs/webpack/VS Code

Answer (score 1):

If you can, setup a [pre-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) on the server side, which will would execute the linter (like [this one](https://github.com/jpolo/node-lint))

That is: add an executable myrepo.git/hooks/pre-receive file which will execute the linter and, if error found, returns '1' (non-0 status will fail the push)

If you cannot add a hook on the server side (GitHub, BitBucket, GitLab, ...) then declare a webhook and install a listener, as described in [`markstory/lint-review`](https://github.com/markstory/lint-review) (which might not be a nodejs linter, but does expose the idea on how to install a webhook/listener)

The idea remains: it is best to enforce it at the server level than at the developers level (where they can skip that test anyway)